# ROS Python Script is not executable when catkin build is done

Tags: python, ros, robotics, catkin

I'm new to ROS.

I have developed a ROS python project. : https://github.com/ildoonet/ros-video-recorder

After cloning the repo into my ros workspace, It is not executed since scripts don't have a permission to run.

It is working fine if I add a permission for execution to the script files.

So.. I have to run 'chmod +x src/{repo_name}/scripts/{script_name}' on every scripts to run this script.

As I have experienced, there are ROS projects that is python based and also is able to be executed right after I download the git. (no need to add a permission)

How can I make my repo to do that? Do I have to add some commands in CMakelists or package.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I can change permissions on script files and commit them on github. Their permission will hold in other machines.